# Custom "Custom Run Configurations" in Intellj

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to create two custom run configuraion runners for testng. The first would be the default TestNG runner and the second would start jetty for integration tests before running them.  I use the CMD+SHIFT+R and CMD+R a lot to run individual tests or a whole class, but it is hard to use this feature whe I cannot start my server before an integration test runs.

Is there a way to set up two configurations, so when I run a test in a package that matches something it uses one configuration, otherwise it will use another?

Comment: A down vote with not information is fairly useless, I would love to know how to improve my question. Please comment if you are inclined to give me a -1.

Comment: Have you looked at maven `profiles` ?

Comment: I have I really like them but was not sure if they are the correct tool for the job

Answer (score 0):

Maven profiles sounds like a good tool for the job, yes.

A simple and very common approach is to split your tests into *unit tests* (which are plain vanilla java code) and *integration tests* (which require other fancy stuff to run).

I see the maven-surefire-plugin supports TestNG, so you are fine there.

Now, to set up jetty, the second pom at [this link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) describes how to start and stop jetty on the maven `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phases.

Then, after you bind the relevant tests to the maven `integration-test` phase, you can execute everything (start jetty -> integration tests -> stop jetty) via this command:

```
mvn verify
```

There are other ways to do it but this is a good starting point.

Good luck.